# Complicated Braid

Tags: tikz-pgf, braids

Is it possible to draw a Braid like this? (with dots and vertical strands)

[image]

I tried to use TikZ braids Package but on the documentation I don't see anything similar to this things.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to tex.SE. Can you show us what you tried and what did not work as expected? Also: do you really think that braid is drawn correctly? Is a braid not something that goes over and under each other all the time? The strands in your drawing seem to be mostly staying in their own level...

Comment: I suggest to read the guide: https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/braids/braids.pdf

Comment: @Sebastiano unfortunately that's exactly the documentation I was referring to and I couldn't find any info on this specific case

Comment: The `braids` library is designed for a very specific style of rendering for braids and uses that specificity to make assumptions on how the braid will look meaning that it can optimise the routine.  For more general knots and links there is the `knots` library and the `spath3` library.  Both will draw diagrams such as this with ease.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can draw this with basic Ti*k*Z commands using `double` to make the crossings (which is what the `braids` package does).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\knotlinewidth}{1pt}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{overcross/.style={double, line width=1.5, white, double=black, double distance=\knotlinewidth}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=\knotlinewidth]
    \draw(0,0)to[out=90,in=-90](5,2)--(5,4);
    \draw[overcross, looseness=1.3](5,6)to[out=-90,in=90](0,3)to[out=-90,in=90](5,0);
    \draw[overcross](5,4)to[out=90,in=-90](0,6);
    \draw[overcross](1,0)--(1,6)(2,0)--(2,6)(4,0)--(4,6);
    \node[font=\huge] at (3,3){$\cdots$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's not how the `braids` package works.  The `braids` package works by inserting gaps in the strands at the right places.  Using `double` is more like how the `knots` library works, only it has a more sophisticated technique which means it avoids issues such as the gap in the vertical part of the strand which you draw in two parts, and it automates calculating the crossings so you don't have to finesse it by hand.

Comment: Thanks for that info @AndrewStacey. I didn't realize the `knots` and `braids` packages used different techniques.